# git multiple user names for the different projects within the same system

Tags: git, git-config

I have a different git repository for my office and a different git repo for my hobby projects.

When I do `git config --global user.name`
the user name changes globally and this creates a confusion
of committing to a repo with user name.

Hence the question is how can i have the same username across all my hobby projects and 
the same username across the office projects. I use the same machine to work on both the places.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

Just use `--local` instead of `--global`. In fact, local is the default so you can just do

```
git config user.email personal@example.org
git config user.name "whatf hobbyist"
```

in one repo, and

```
git config user.email work@example.com
git config user.name "whatf at work"
```

in another repo

The values will then be stored in in the `.git/config` for that repo rather than your global configuration file.

Comment: shouldn't user.name contain the person's _name_, not email address? `user.email` contains the email address

Comment: @JonathanWakely I think you're right. I'm not sure where I got the example to put both values in one setting. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @mikej `git commit --author=` allows that syntax, but not setting through config or environment variables.

Comment: Ah, cheers @Joe, that might be where I've used it in the past.

Comment: Can't we have something like .ssh/config 
Host *.workdomain 
email work@example.com
Host *github.com 
personal@example.org
?

Comment: When I do this, it does not ask me for my password and does not allow me to push to the repository; it just assumes I'm using the global. This did not work for me.

Comment: Hi @ProQ - this question/answer is about controlling the name and email address recorded when you make a commit. If you're having trouble pushing to a remote that sounds like a different question.

Comment: Ah, yes. My issue is with pushing to a remote. Committing works just fine for me. Thank you.

Comment: @ProQ, if you're using SSH for auth, check out the instructions in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996). be sure to read the first couple of comments though, because the gist itself doesn't clearly explain how SSH hosts work..

Comment: what can you do if the local repo has multiple submodules ? manually add the name in all submodules  or is there an accelerator ?

Answer (score 14):

Omit the `--global` from your call to `git config`:

```
git config user.name "A. U. Thor"
```

This will set the property in the current repository.