# git: how to have per project configuration?

Tags: git

I'm using git for several project at the same time. Apparently I have a global setting with username, etc. What I want to maintain is different user name, email, etc for different project. How to achieve this?

Comment: You can use the --local config option instead of global see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063176/git-multiple-user-names-for-the-different-projects-within-the-same-system

Answer (score 14):

Just use the `git config` command without the `--global` parameter.

Instead of

```
git config --global user.name "lang2"
```

Type

```
git config user.name "lang2"
```

As [described in the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), global configurations are stored in `~/.gitconfig`, and per repository configuration resides in `.git/config`.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to add a tracked configuration as well? Such that the config will be available on each checkout? I was thinking about adding a `.gitattributes` filter to clean up files prior to comitting, and it would make sense to do this for each collaborator.