# Git error: Permission denied to Repo.git to user Me

Tags: git

I have two github accounts, one that I use for personal projects, and another that I use for work, just like the person in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063176/git-multiple-user-names-for-the-different-projects-within-the-same-system).

In this scenario, I am trying to push to something using my personal project account, and it's not letting me.

I have set the local name and email to be my person project account (the global is my work project account) using the instructions in the answer to that question, but when I push it denies permission to my global account, not the local account (without even giving me the chance to type in a password for my personal project account).

How can I have some projects push with my personal project account credentials, and other projects push with my work account credentials?

EDIT:
The specific command I am getting the error on is `git push --set-upstream origin tail_recognition`

What I get back is `remote: Permission to Repo.git denied to WorkUsername.`

When I do `git config user.name` I get back my personal username, and when I do `git config user.email` I get back the email for my person username. So why don't I get a chance to sign in with my personal username, and why isn't permission denied to my personal username?

EDIT:
I noticed something weird: When I do `git config --global user.name` I don't get the name that the permission is being denied to, so I'm not sure what's up with that.

Answer (score 0):

To set a username for a single repository, you need to call the following command: `git config user.name "YOUR USER NAME"`. You can check that it has been set correctly by calling `git config user.name`. If this still doesn't work, you can try deleting your credentials from 'Credential Manager'(on Windows) and resetting your credentials.

Comment: git config user.name gives me back my personal account name, but when I try to push, permission is denied to my global work account name.

Comment: Try calling git config user.email "your email" to set the email address of the account

Comment: I have already done that: `git config user.email` gives me the email for my personal account.

Comment: What Operating system are you on

Comment: I am on Windows 10

Comment: I've also made a few edits to my question to add more details.

Comment: If you type in credential helper into Windows search you can go to an application that lets you view all your credentials that you have set up. Locate all the credentials for git/github and delete them. Then set all your credentials again-global first then local. This should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can define a username and email for every project. You can add that to your `.git/config` file or use `git config user.name "Your name"`. In Git you have two ways. With the option `--global` you define the global username options. When you remove that option it's the config for the actual project you're in.

Here is the way in the Github documentation:

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/